# Finding descendants of div with specific class

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website and want to get all the descendants of a specific div class. For example, suppose I have a website that looks like the following:

[Edit: The question's author indicates in the comments that all of the `div` elements should be at the same level; I've therefore taken the liberty of closing them in this sample code.]

```
<div class = "blah">
    <p></p>
</div>

<div class = "i-want-this">
    <p></p>
    <p><a href= "http://www.google.com"></a></p>
</div>

<div class = "i-want-this">
    <p></p>
    <li></li>
        <p>meh</p>
    <li></li>
</div>
```

I want all the descendants of each instance of the div class "i-want-this" and to ignore the other divs. I can specify those divs in a find_all

```
div = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'i-want-this'})
```

But that just creates a list of all of that. I also see that you can grab descendants by

```
soup.div.descendants
```

But I don't know how to specify which classes of div tags I want to include. I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Would you consider using another software product (ie, other than BeautifulSoup) that is better for representing hierarchical structures compactly? Both lxml and scrapy, for instance, offer the ability to use xpath expressions.

Comment: In your sample HTML, do you really mean to have the second `div` element nested within the first?

Comment: All the divs are on the same "level" so should not be nested within each other. I believe I am using an lxml parser within bs4 here, but I can also do this with some brute force loops in Selenium. I think I just want to find all descendants (so children of children) of a specific div class. The numbers and types of descendants will vary widely (poorly written webpage).

Comment: Also, if you have a way to do this in scrapy, I would love to see some example code! I don't know how to use scrapy that well and the documentation reads a little cryptic to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, I came up with this solution. The "children" object captured all children of 'div' and successive children; then I iterated over that

```
children = soup.findChildren('div', {'class': 'i-want-this'})

content = []
for item in children:   
    item = [content for content in item.text.split('\n') if len(content)>0]

    # Create string from separate list items to all be listed in content
    item = ' '.join(item)
    content.append(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you want:

```
div = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'i-want-this'})

for e in div:
    print (e.descendents) #or append to list, or whatever you're trying to do.
```

Comment: That solution returns descendant generator objects and when I try to get the text (e.g. e.descendants.text) it returns an error because text isn't an attribute of generators :(

Answer (score 0):

I shoved your HTML into a file called `temp.htm`.

You need only a tiny part of scrapy for tasks like this: `Selector`. Just feed your HTML into it, then use its `xpath` method.

In this case I can specify one of the two `div` elements with the `class` of interest, by number, then ask for all of its descendants and then `extract` what's in those. The result in each case is a list of elements descending from the children of the `div`.

```
>>> from scrapy.selector import Selector
>>> HTML = open('temp.htm').read()
>>> selector = Selector(text=HTML)
>>> selector.xpath('.//div[@class="i-want-this"][1]/*').extract()
['<p></p>', '<p><a href="http://www.google.com"></a></p>']
>>> selector.xpath('.//div[@class="i-want-this"][2]/*').extract()
['<p></p>', '<li>', '<p>meh</p>', '<li>']
```

[The xpath cheatsheet](http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/xpath.html) can be really useful at times like these.

Comment: Thanks Bill - I'll check this out. I'm not that familiar with scrapy but hear it can be powerful in webscraping tasks